Some of the Image on my webpage are shrinking, but other are not shring even with same properties
If I resize my window,the div/img in the computerSection is not shrinking, whereas the the div/images in the userSection are shrinking when.
Both of them have exactly same CSS, I've usde flexbox in both of them and there is no other flex property added.
I am not able to figure out why the image on the right is not shrinking?


.userSection {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.computerSection{
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 border-left: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 2px;
 padding: 0px 40px;
 flex-grow: 1;
}

#bodyDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.headerDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.headerSubDiv {
  transition: 0.7s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.userAddOn {
  border-width: 3px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.computerImg {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: brown;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<div id="bodyDiv">
  <div class="userSection">
    <div class="headerTitle">
      <p>Player please choose:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="headerDiv">
      <div class="headerSubDiv"><img class="userAddOn" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20414000/pexels-photo-20414000/free-photo-of-gentoo-penguin-on-snow.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"></div>
      <div class="headerSubDiv"><img class="userAddOn" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20414000/pexels-photo-20414000/free-photo-of-gentoo-penguin-on-snow.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"></div>
      <div class="headerSubDiv"><img class="userAddOn" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20414000/pexels-photo-20414000/free-photo-of-gentoo-penguin-on-snow.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="computerSection">
    <div class="headerTitle">
      <p>Computer's choice:</p>
    </div>
    <div class=" headerSubDiv"><img class="computerImg" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20414000/pexels-photo-20414000/free-photo-of-gentoo-penguin-on-snow.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"></div>
  </div>
</div>




would adding a <div class="headerDiv">...</div> around the computer's headerSubDiv item(s) help?

You have no styles for computerSection; where are they?

@JonSG I did try that. Didn't work

@Kalnode Missed including it. Added now. It was always there, didn't work

You have not defined .computerSection
add a comma after .userSection and add .computerSection there, then it will work
.userSection, .computerSection {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   border-right: solid;
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 0px 100px;
   flex-grow: 1;
}


Missed including it. Added now. It was always there, didn't work
